# Помогите разобраться с памятью

Tags: c++, оптимизация

Есть простая задача:

> **Задача**   Ваша программа должна определять, можно ли из двух списков целых чисел выбрать по одному числу так, чтобы в сумме они
>   составили
>   10000.
>
> **Исходные данные**  Состоят из двух списков — одного, потом другого. Формат каждого из этих списков таков: в первой строчке записано
>   количество Ni чисел в i-м списке, далее в Ni строчках по одному числу
>   в строке записаны сами списки. Выполняются неравенства 1 ≤ Ni ≤ 50000,
>   все элементы списков лежат в диапазоне от –32768 до
>   32767. Первый список упорядочен по возрастанию, второй — по убыванию.
>
> **Результат**  На выходе следует записать YES, если из списков можно выбрать по числу, которые в сумме дадут 10000 и NO в противном случае.

Я реализовал 2 решения:

№1

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);

    int n1;
    cin >> n1;
    int* nums1 = new int[n1];
    for(int i=0; i<n1; i++){
        cin>>nums1[i];
    }
    int n2;
    cin >> n2;
    set<int> nums2;
    int t;
    for(int i=0; i<n2; i++){
        cin >> t;
        nums2.insert(t);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<n1; i++){
        if(nums2.find(10000-nums1[i]) != nums2.end()){
            cout << "YES";
            return 0;
        }
    }

    cout << "NO";

    return 0;
}
```

№2

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);

    unsigned int n1;
    cin >> n1;
    set<int> nums1;
    int t;
    for(int i=0; i<n1; i++){
        cin >> t;
        nums1.insert(t);
    }

    unsigned int n2;
    cin >> n2;

    bool res = false;

    for(int i=0; i<n2; i++){
        cin >> t;
        if(nums1.find(10000 - t) != nums1.end())
            res = true;
    }

    cout << ((res)?"YES":"NO");

    return 0;
}
```

В итоге, после тестов, программа №1 использовала 1 468 КБ, а №2 2 020 КБ. В №1 я создавал массив и множество, когда в №2 только множество, то есть, по идее, памяти нужно меньше. Этого я не могу понять...

P.S. Только учусь, если не сложно, можете дать советы по оптимизации

Comment: Вы можете сэкономить несколько десятков килобайт (теоретически - 10000 * 2 *2  порядка 40 кб) если будете использовать массивы типа  short, а не int - входные данные как раз подходят. У Вас одна программа имеет квадратичную сложность, другая - n ln(n). Но ее можно ужать до просто линейной сложности - массивы уже отсортированы.

Comment: @KoVadim, а где квадратичная сложность, я что-то не вижу?

Comment: а нет, там также n ln (n) - почему то увидел там вектор, а не множество.

Answer (score 2):

Задачка то олимпиадная, скорость работы можно увеличить шикарно. Намёк первый: выбираем первое число из первого списка, ищем во втором место, где сумма `nums1[0]+nums2[i]>10000 and nums1[0]+nums2[i+1]<10000` можно просто перебором начиная с нулевого индекса. Намёк второй: все числа из второго списка по индексам `0 .. i` будут всегда в сумме давать число больше 10000. Так-что работать можно начиная с индекса **i+1**. В первом списке элемент по нулевому индексу тоже уже не участвует, у него поиск делаем начиная с индекса **1**. Дальше выполняем тоже-самое, но массивы меняем ролями. Берём `num2[i+1]` и ищем в первом списке место **j** чтобы `num1[j]+num2[i+1]<10000 and num1[j+1]+num2[i+1]>10000`. Поиск делаем линейно **1**,**2**, и т.д. Успехов.

Comment: намёк 3. Второй массив можно не хранить :D (можно и первый не хранить но это читать надо по хитрому)